# Deserved or undeserved Epic badge earning?

Tags: support, badges

I have just earned this badge, but https://stackoverflow.com/reputation shows this:

> earned at least 200 reputation on **47** days

https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/145/epic shows:

> Awarded 19 hours ago to

Whereas I have just been awarded. What am I missing?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85363/epic-badge-received-too-early

Comment: @Bart: thanks, that seems to explain half of the question. (Whether it is good to have inconsistency between the badge count and /reputation is a different question...)

Comment: @Bart: [this is even more radical](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61091/why-did-i-get-the-epic-badge/61173#61173) (33 ;-) ).

Comment: Some might say it's even more epic ;)

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate of [Epic badge received too early?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85363/178816)

Comment: @TravisJ we don't do cross-site duplicate closures. If anything, feel free to answer the question here if you can address all points and link to the MSE post if you must.

Comment: @Bart - It can be done, just like that. This is how it was done when the meta sites were first split and I am not sure why it would be less useful now. This badge issue is related to the exchange in general and not specifically to SO. While it can be answered here, it already has an answer elsewhere. I know that duplication is not frowned on, but paraphrasing a whole discussion is overkill.

Comment: @TravisJ:  first, the link from Jeff Artwood seems to be more of a duplicate for the first part of the question than the one you linked. In other words, your linked duplicate could be closed as duplicate, too. Secondly, how is that answering the 19 hours ago vs. now issue in the second part of the question? Also, Bart seems to be right if you look around.

Comment: @lpapp - This link? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52800/slightly-premature-legendary-badge It may look like Atwood, but that is because he last edited it (to place the status-review tag on it). Actually it was Pekka's post - and contained no answers. As a result, it wouldn't be a candidate. Unless of course you meant a different link in which case please let me know.

Comment: As for the latter part of your question you are correct, it is not addressed. For badges which are not earned often (congrats, it is a nice achievement), and for which take some time to calculate, the script doesn't run daily. Thus, it took a few days for it to be rewarded, but the script did run right at 0 GMT.

Comment: @TravisJ: not that link; the one I pasted above. Also, it was awarded nearly instantly right after I earned 200 reputation on the 47th day, not independently from that due to the 46th day at 0 GMT. It would be an odd coincidence if your theory is true. ^_^